# I'm not able install deluge on my Kali

Tags: linux, apt, kali-linux, repository

Greetings!

I'm trying to install a torrent client to my Kali Linux. The deluge apt isn't included in Kali's official repositories. So, I tried:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:deluge-team/stable
 Deluge 2.0 Stable Builds

For more information, visit http://deluge-torrent.org

As the maintainer of this PPA, you can now support me on Patreon: https://www.patreon.com/deluge_cas
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~deluge-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpr4by1_0h/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpr4by1_0h/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C5E6A5ED249AD24C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Deluge Team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

**If I try to update the apt:**

```
apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease 
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/stable/ubuntu groovy InRelease         
Hit:4 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch InRelease                 
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/stable/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:5 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease [23.8 kB]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/stable/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**My sources.list is:**

```
# deb cdrom:[Kali GNU/Linux 2020.3rc2 _Kali-last-snapshot_ - Official amd64 NETINST wi>

# deb cdrom:[Kali GNU/Linux 2020.3rc2 _Kali-last-snapshot_ - Official amd64 NETINST wi>

deb http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali-rolling main non-free contrib

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

I'm not able to install qbittorrent as well for almost similar reason. Kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question? ... i do not see one in your post

Comment: Sorry about that. I want to install deluge torrent client. I'm not able to do it because of the errors posted. If I use apt-get install, I get an error saying E: Package 'deluge' has no installation candidate.

Comment: that is a description of what is happening ... it is not a question

Comment: If you are inquiring about adding a repo, the Kali isn't the distro for you.

Answer (score 3):

> *I'm trying to install a torrent client to my Kali Linux*

and

> *The deluge apt isn't included in Kali's official repositories*

The simple answer is that then you don't do that.

Kali itself says that mixing repositories from other distributions is the [fastest way to break your Kali installation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories). If you want to use Kali for anything other than what it is designed to do, then don't use Kali.